# How to modify an array to get another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a manually filled array with directory names that are used to run a function for image modification. Number and names of these directories changes frequently, so to simplify it I scan the main directory to get the names of the subdirectories. The problem is that the format of this directory array is not as I need it.

This is the manually filled array:

```
$aManipulations = array(
    array('x109_110x110'),
    array('x1380'),
    array('x1800'),
    array('x2012'),
    array('x387'),
    array('x40'),
    array('x561'),
    array('x60'),
    array('x640'),
    array('x669'),
    array('x671'),
    array('x700'),
);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => x109_110x110
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => x1380
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => x1800
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => x2012
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => x387
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => x40
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => x561
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => x60
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => x640
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => x669
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => x671
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => x700
        )

)
```

Other array generated by scan dir:

```
$dir = glob('images/onthefly/products/' . '*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
$dir = str_replace("images/onthefly/products/", "", $dir);
$aManipulations = array(
    array($dir),
);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => x109_110x110
                    [1] => x1380
                    [2] => x1800
                    [3] => x2012
                    [4] => x387
                    [5] => x40
                    [6] => x561
                    [7] => x60
                    [8] => x640
                    [9] => x669
                    [10] => x671
                    [11] => x700
                )

        )

)
```

So what has to be done to transform the automatically filled array?

###################### Update ######################

```
foreach ($aManipulations as $aManipulation) {
    smarty_modifier_manipulateImage(
            DIR_WS_ORIGINAL_IMAGES . $aQuery['products_image'],
            $aManipulation[0],
            isset($aManipulation[1]) ? $aManipulation[1] : '',
            isset($aManipulation[2]) ? $aManipulation[2] : false
    );
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you why you want to have an array consisting of arrays with only one value? To me the last result looks way more logic. What am I missing?

Comment: And just using the `$dir` array rather than putting it in another array i,e, `$aManipulations = array( array($dir) );` would be even more logical. why bury an array in an array when there is only one array

Comment: I updated the code above, maybe that helps?

Comment: The one like it is in manually array

Comment: a) manually filed array b) automatically filled array c) b) must be like a) better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you need to manipulate your array generated by scan dir as that of the manually filled array.

As you can see the $dir is an array  so you can loop through it to access individual directory and subdirectory names. You just have to create an array with that name.

You can do it using `for` loop.

```
$requiredArray = array();
foreach ($dir as $name) {
array_push($requiredArray, array($name));
}
print_r($requiredArray);
```

Or Using array_map:

```
$dir = array('x109_110x110','x1380','x1800','x2012','x387','x40','x561','x60','x640','x669','x671','x700');
$func = function(String $value): Array {
    return array($value);
};

print_r(array_map($func, $dir));
```

Comment: Your previous code worked, all you had to do was change the `: String` return type into `: Array` return type

Answer (score 2):

If you must convert the `glob()` generated array into the array structure you have used before then

```
foreach( $dir as $d ) {
    $aManipulations[][] = $d;
}
```

will do that for you